# How to insert .txt file value into database and move into folder in php

Tags: php, mysql

code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $filename = $_FILES['field']['name'];
        $path = "attandance_file/".basename($_FILES['field']['name']);
        $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['field']['tmp_name'],$path);
        $data = file_get_contents($path, NULL, NULL, 0, 60000);
        $query = "insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)value('".$data."')";
        echo $query;
        unlink($path);
    }
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="field" name="field" />
        <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This is my .txt file example.txt

```
No  TMNo    EnNo    Name    INOUT   Mode    DateTime
1    1       1                0      0      2017/01/03 16:41:22
2    1       1                0      0      2017/01/03 16:41:22
3    1       1                0      0      2017/01/03 16:42:39
4    1       1                0      0      2017/01/03 16:42:39
5    1       2                0      0      2017/01/03 16:59:42
```

When I click on the submit button and echo $query, the response I get back looks like this:

```
insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)value('No  TMNo    EnNo    Name    INOUT   Mode    DateTime 1  1   1   0   0   2017/01/03 16:41:22')
```

In this query, it inserts values in a single column but I want to insert in a separate column like

```
insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)value('No','TMNo','EnNo','Name','INOUT','Mode','DateTime','1','1','1','0','0','2017/01/03 16:41:22');
```

So, How can I do this ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: can anybody help me

Comment: First up, it's `values`, not `value` in your queries. Your second query won't work because you have 7 fields and want to insert 13 values. You might want to take a look at [fgetcsv()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), parse your .txt file and insert every row into your db

Comment: What separates the values in the text file? Spaces? Tabs? Something else?